# jQuery iterate some div

Tags: jquery, loops

I have html:

```
<div class="box">
    <input name="radio-1" value="1" type="radio" class="radio">
    <div class="hidden_box">
    some content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <input name="radio-2" value="1" type="radio" class="radio">
    <div class="hidden_box">
    some content
    </div>
</div>
```

.... and so on

When I click on radio button I need to make "hidden_box" visible in this "box" div. How can I do it?

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your Q with jQuery, I'll use that:

```
$('.radio').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.hidden_box').show();
});
```

See working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/apvew/).

UPDATE: If you want to apply this to all present and future '.box' items, use:

```
$('.radio').live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.hidden_box').show();
});
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to work when you add more '.box' elements, as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".radio") //select the radio buttons
           .click( function() { //Assign a click handler
               $(this).next().show(); //Get the element that comes after this one and make it visible
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.radio').click(function(i,v){
  $(this).next('.hidden_box').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.radio').click(function(){
     $('.hidden_box', $(this).parent()).show();
})
```

Will work, even if hidden_box isn't the next DOM element. The second parameter in a jquery selector is the scope.

UPDATE: Using find(), as demonstrated elsewhere in the answers looks a bit cleaner to me

Comment: Yeah, whoops, got confused with checkboxes

Comment: The original approach would have worked as well, if you replaced both occurrences of `this` with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.box input').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.hidden_box').toggle();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmRdg/